# Python dictionary data is not getting updated if same dictionary is used again and again

Tags: python

I tried creating a dictionary which holds set of dictionary. For that i did write below.
But since everything is object in python, even though i have assigned new students to dictionary student,
when i print data, i can see only 123 data. Need to understand this behaviour in details and how to over come this problem.

```py
students = {}

student = {}
student['id'] = 123
student['first_name'] = 'Raj'
student['last_name'] = 'Nath'

students[123] = student

student['id'] = 124
student['first_name'] = 'Naveen'
student_1['last_name'] = 'Jain'

students[124] = student

print(students)
```

Comment: You have a bug in your code (student_1 should be student) other than that my output is a dictionary containing 2 keys. Not quite sure what output you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `students[123] = student` student dictionary is stored under key `123`. But it isn't copied. Still under `student` variable there is the same directory which you are accessing in:

```py
student['id'] = 124
student['first_name'] = 'Naveen'
student_1['last_name'] = 'Jain'
```

As it is still the same dictionary, you are overriding old values with new values.

If you would like to copy dictionary use:

```
students[123] = student.copy()
```

But more accurate would be creating new empty dictionary after assigning:

```
students[123] = student
student = {}
```

Python is almost always passing-by-reference to reduce number of operations on memory. You can read more about it [here](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you did not create a new dictionary. When you ran the line `students[123] = student` you passed the dictionary that was stored in the variable `student`. After that, you then proceeded to modify that same dictionary. I would recommend either creating a copy of the dictionary (`students[123] = student.copy()`) and storing that in `students` or creating a new dictionary for each student.

Using copy:

```py
students = {}

student = {}
student['id'] = 123
student['first_name'] = 'Raj'
student['last_name'] = 'Nath'

students[123] = student.copy() # This stores a copy of the dictionary

student['id'] = 124
student['first_name'] = 'Naveen'
student['last_name'] = 'Jain'

students[124] = student

print(students)
```

Using new dictionary:

```py
students = {}

student = {}
student['id'] = 123
student['first_name'] = 'Raj'
student['last_name'] = 'Nath'

students[123] = student

student = {} # Create a new dictionary to be used for the new student
student['id'] = 124
student['first_name'] = 'Naveen'
student['last_name'] = 'Jain'

students[124] = student

print(students)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach stores many times **the same** `student` **dictionary** into the `students` one.  All the different instances `students[0], ..., students[n]` in effect point to the same object, that contains the value assigned in the last update you committed.

To make things work, you must instantiate  **a new dictionary** each time you input the data for a new student — I find particularly convenient to use the class constructor in place of the usual literal, but probably it's just me…

```
students = {}
students[123] = dict(id=123, first_name='Raj', last_name='Nath')
students[124] = dict(id=124, first_name='Naveen', last_name='Jain')
```

Further, obeying the principle of least duplication, it could be

```
students = {}
students[123] = dict(first_name='Raj', last_name='Nath')
students[124] = dict(first_name='Naveen', last_name='Jain')
```

---

*ps1: of course there is also a competing principle of maximum duplication and you should choose the one you prefer ;-)*

---

*ps2: `id` is a Python builtin function, you can assign an integer to `id`, Python is liberal, but other parts of your program are now in danger of mysteriously breaking…*